# Remove admob ads temporaly

Tags: android, admob, temporal

I want to disable admob ads temporaly without remove the code in my app.
I want can disable and enable from the console of admob.
 ¿I can do it?,
I search in the options and i dont see nothing.

Comment: have you tried test mode or comment `adView.loadAd()` on your java code or put `ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"` on your xml file?

Comment: u dont understand it i want to remove it without touch the code.From admob console for example.

Comment: I dont believe thats possible

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mediation, you can turn off all your mediation networks. You can't turn off your site ID though. A workaround is to set up a house ad instead to serve to your apps instead of an ad.

Comment: maybe i put a transparent ads. i need think it

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);`, or `adView.setVisibility(AdView.INVISIBLE);`so it "is" not here (is invisble) and you does not have to delete code.
The difference is: with GONE, it "goes" away so it does not take space in your layout and is invible, while with INVISIBLE, it only appears as invisible without dissapearing from layout, so it takes a space in it.